# How to copy a message without the message sender's name on Telegram?

Tags: telegram

Until not long ago when you copied a message on Telegram, only the message text was copied. This was a distinguishable feature of Telegram when compared with WhatsApp where messages where copied prefixed with the original sender name and date.

More recently things have turned around and now WhatsApp is copying messages without the sender and date info, while Telegram is prefixing its copied messages with the original sender's name.

How can I copy a message without the message sender's name on Telegram?

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways on Telegram to copy messages:

1. Tap and hold + copy = will copy the message **with** the sender's name
2. Tap + copy = will copy the message **without** the sender's name

Comment: Tnx for sharing, was looking for a solution for this as well.